# Encoding query db in json returns null value

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

I have a DB result to encode in json, previously I had encoding problems when importing datas into the db (strange chars on phpmyadmin) but now I fixed it by utf8_decode() before inserting datas.

So now I retrive my datas but something's wrong with strings...

```
echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($product);
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump( json_encode($product));
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br>'.mb_detect_encoding($product->name);
        echo '<br>'.$product->name;
        echo '<br>'.mb_convert_encoding($product->name, 'ISO-8859-1');
        $product->name = 'H2O AUDIO Waterproof-Ohrhörer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY';
        echo '<br>Revu encode: '.mb_detect_encoding($product->name);
        echo '<br>'.mb_detect_encoding($product->name);
        echo '<br>Revu: '.$product->name;
        echo '<br>'.mb_convert_encoding($product->name, 'ISO-8859-1');
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump( json_encode($product));
```

This gives me:

```
object(Application_Model_Product)#42 (13) {
  ["id_product"]=>
  string(6) "359805"
  ["id_community_ask"]=>
  NULL
  ["barcode"]=>
  string(13) "3000000010907"
  ["name"]=>
  string(51) "H2O AUDIO Waterproof-Ohrhörer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["image"]=>
  NULL
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["nb_votes_halal"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["nb_votes_harram"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["date_created:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["date_edited:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["updated:protected"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["imported:protected"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

string(173) "{"id_product":"359805","id_community_ask":null,"barcode":"3000000010907","name":null,"description":null,"image":null,"status":"2","nb_votes_halal":"0","nb_votes_harram":"0"}"

UTF-8
H2O AUDIO Waterproof-Ohrhörer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY
H2O AUDIO Waterproof-Ohrhörer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY
Revu encode: UTF-8
UTF-8
Revu: H2O AUDIO Waterproof-OhrhÃ¶rer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY
H2O AUDIO Waterproof-OhrhÃ¶rer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY
string(227) "{"id_product":"359805","id_community_ask":null,"barcode":"3000000010907","name":"H2O AUDIO Waterproof-Ohrh\u00f6rer Surge Pro Mini BA1-GY","description":null,"image":null,"status":"2","nb_votes_halal":"0","nb_votes_harram":"0"}"
```

And you cans see that 'name' field contains something but when I encode in json it tells 'null'...I kwnow json works only in utf8 that's why I called an mb_detect_encoding to make sure I'm in utf8...

Any idea of why 'name' field returns 'null'?

Comment: can you try calling json_last_error() after the encoding to see it there are any errors http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: try using:    $product->name = iconv("YOURCHARSET","utf8",$product->name);

Answer (score 0):

you need to do either:

```
mb_convert_encoding($product->name,"utf8","THE_NAME_CHARSET");
```

or:

```
$product->name = iconv("THE_NAME_CHARSET","utf8",$product->name);
```